# Can anyone help me identify this font type from the logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

I want to identify this font, can someone help me with this ?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. We have [special requirements for font ID questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366). Can you please review these and then [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/152472/edit) accordingly. Thanks.  Also be aware that often logos use custom designed lettering. So there is a possibility it may not actually be a font, or it could be an existing font that was modified.

Comment: I'd say it's a collection of hand drawn paths, not a font, especially for a logo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's [Neuropol](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/neuropol). (Neuropol X Regular or Bold)

[image: Adobe Font Family]

You can easily find fonts in Images by using some sort of "Font-Image-Recognition" like [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/visual-search-adobe-fonts.html) from Adobe (you don't need a creative cloud (CC) account, it's free)

There are many other free choices (without sign-up) like [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator) or [fontspring](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) available.

Regards, OrangeBlueHoney

Comment: Added one, thanks for the tip ^^